# Ghost folders in /Volumes

Tags: macos, finder, hard-drive, mount

I've had a problem today where when I plug my external HDD in, it creates a ghost folder in `/Volumes` with the same name, causing my hard drive to change it's path to `/Volumes/HDD 1`. This is messing with programs that direct to `/Volumes/HDD`.
Is there someway to fix this? Also, my harddrive has an issue where even a small bump can cause it to give the error of it not being removed properly, so this could potentially be the cause of it.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you sure the folder isn't there before you plug in the drive?

Comment: It's there before, during and after. If I delete it then it just creates a new one when I net plug the drive in

Answer (score 2):

Yes - premature ejection can cause these ghosts.

You would need to script a cleanup that uses `df` and `diskutil list` and `ls /Volumes` to remove the ghost entries.

I typically do this by hand as it happens very infrequently to me.

Comment: How would I go about this? And would this then allow my HDD to mount at the location `/Volumes/HDD`?

Comment: @AdamBreguet Best to start a new question. Do you know any scripting language? If not - coursera, lynda to get started. If so, you can break down these tools and ask what they do. You could even run one and post the output as a question and ask how to understand it. It will be hard to do a tutorial in the comments.

Comment: How exactly do you use those commands to get rid of the ghost?  It seems like each of them can help me see the ghost, but I can't see the right way to get rid of it.

Comment: And in fact, the ghost does not show up in diskutil list or df.  Only in ls /Volumes